# Accessing generic type of nested property

Tags: typescript, generics, monads

I am trying to implement a monad in TypeScript; specifically the `join` method in [this example](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/appendix_b.html#maybe).

The problem to be solved is as follows:

```js
const mm3 = new Maybe(new Maybe(3)); // Maybe<Maybe<number>>
const m3 = mm3.join();               // Maybe<number>
```

The `join` method un-nests the two `Maybe`s. However there are three states that `Maybe` can be in when calling `join`. The expected output is shown below.

```js
new Maybe(new Maybe(3)).join(); // Maybe<number>(3)
new Maybe<number>(null).join(); // Maybe<number>(null)
new Maybe(3).join();            // 3 - Not the normal use-case for join()
```

---

#### Vague attempt at an implementation...

```js
interface IMonad<T> {
    join(): T; // Works for cases #1 and #3 above but
               // really I want to express that we're
               // returning an IMonad<number> in the examples.
               // Or even better, a Maybe<number> in the case of Maybe 
}

class Maybe<T> implements IMonad<T> {

    private value: T | null;

    public constructor(value: T | null | undefined) {
        this.value = (value === null || value === undefined) ? null : value;
    }

    public join(): T {
        if (this.value === null) {
            return Maybe.of<??>(null); // 'number' in these examples
        } else {
            return this.value;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm struggling to get my head around how this might work. Any ideas? Is TypeScript even capable or do I need [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's straightforward enough to implement individual *instances* of `Monad`, like `Maybe`, as long as you don't want to represent `Monad` itself, which really needs [higher-kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)... and TypeScript has no direct support for those, as you know.  (It seems that [some people](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213#issuecomment-415694540) have [come up with](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213#issuecomment-485471165) some *indirect* support, but nothing clean enough that I'd want to recommend here)

If you want to strongly type `Maybe.prototype.join()` without worrying about anything called "`Monad`" in the code, I'd suggest using a generic [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters), like so:

```
class Maybe<T> {
  constructor(public value?: T) {}
  join<U>(this: Maybe<Maybe<U>>) { // this parameter
    return new Maybe(
      typeof this.value === "undefined" ? undefined : this.value.value
    );
  }
}
```

(I am only dealing with `undefined` as the "nothing" value here; you can add support for `null` if you need it)

A `this` parameter requires that it be called as a method on an object of matching type.  So by having `join()`'s `this` be `Maybe<Maybe<U>>` for some generic `U`, we guarantee that `this.value` will, if not `undefined`, itself have a `value` property.

Let's test it:

```
const mm3 = new Maybe(new Maybe(3)); // Maybe<Maybe<number>>
const m3 = mm3.join(); // Maybe<number>
```

That's exactly what you wanted to see.  Also note that calling `m3.join()` is a compile-time error:

```
const oops = m3.join(); // error!
/* The 'this' context of type 'Maybe<number>' is not assignable to method's
  'this' of type 'Maybe<Maybe<unknown>>'.  Type 'number' is not assignable 
  to type 'Maybe<unknown>'. */
```

That looks like the right behavior to me; you can't `join()` a non-nested monad.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyYE8BGBTAPAFQHzQN4ChppgB7AOwgBcAnAV2EpOoAoAHWpEAS2GgDcwIWigD8ALmgYAlHgC+haACsSXMmgCqWZpQAWXCBPjJ0R1BqxYZBIkWopKtamWhkUAdziJUzBTeiUEVhQSADN-PQgAOgEhFGgAXkToACJaMgATFBDVFHTk6BFoNMzs13ToCV19aMFhGtjfaCkAbgV5eXxSCkpoAFtegGYEl3dPY2ZXD1MUZgGpFugAekWxs2m0Mlpe1GoLfE7yKj6h+L7ByOVVZgXl1fRN7ZRdg+7oEhJWGFPzy7Jr5qWKye1CYAEJ8IsAFSSHRxADkVQgcOI5EoKAAHj1Qv5AvD1g8dlhkfoXCQepAIFwAOZkMCcOKMPr2HQkdJwiAKBERZHYgJBaBw9brNIAazIJDcZAscMiRAwuIFBKexJg4vJUGptPp0AUjL5eK86FF4slRNlkMW+CAA)

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you! Shame about the higher kinded types but this is a pragmatic alternative. I didn't know about typing `this`. Thanks.